# Selenium Tests add Cookies after login

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, mocha.js, svelte

So i working with one Project written on Svelte. For this application i need to write many tests using Selenium JS. I try to write some of the tests to check the Page-content, but i got a problem with authorisation... By my application on home page there is a button, after press the button it will generating in java backend special access Token, which expires in 15 minutes. So my test look likes :

```
const URL = "http://localhost:5000"



describe('SVELTE CLIENT APP', function() {
    var driver;
    before(function () {
        driver = new webdriver.Builder()
            .forBrowser('chrome')
            .build();

    });


describe('Navigation with Auth', async function () {


        it('Experiment', async function (){

         
            //get current domain 
            await driver.get(URL);

            //Authorisation Click on Button 
            await driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('body > div > fieldset:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(2) > span > button > span')).click();

            
            // try to get actual Cookies after Authorisation, but it doesn't work 
            await driver.manage().getCookies().then(function (cookie) {
                console.log(cookie);
            });
            
            // Set the Cookies per Hand
            await driver.manage().addCookie({name:"AUTH_COOKIE", value:"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJicm9tYmVydGplQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsIm5iZiI6MTYzNzA5MjE2MywiaWQiOiIxIiwibG9naW4iOiJicm9tYmVydGplIiwiZXhwIjoxNjM3MDkzMDYzLCJlbWFpbCI6ImJyb21iZXJ0amVAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOiJS..."});
            // get a page with the cookie
            
            
            //....
        });
    });
```

So how i can get this Cookie value after Authorisation using Selenium? Any idea ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtI8C.png)

Comment: You don't need to get or add the cookie.  It'll be sent with every request.  You probably can't get it from Selenium because it is set as HTTP-Only.  (Though you could get it from the request headers...)

Comment: One thing you do need to do, though, is to wait for the browser to get the request from the server to write the cookie, and then for the browser to do that.  It's a small amount of time, but if you don't wait, the cookie will not be set.  (For instance, if you used a .get() right after clicking your login button the cookie would not be set.)

Comment: Thank you for your response! So actually i need to use driver.wait after clicking and then again getCookies method ?

Comment: you could wait for an expected condition to appear, yes.  (Something that appears in the DOM after logging in.)  You won't need to get the cookies if the only reason you are doing that is to set them again.  They will already be set.  (and you may not be able to get the cookies that way since they are set as http-only.)

Comment: The reason why i need to get this Cookies, that i want to set them again. If i want go to other url, like driver.get(localhost:5000/user) i must be authorised to see the content and Information of User, to do that i need this SessionsCookies.( The authorisation is only possible by localhost:5000)

Comment: the way cookies work is they are sent along with every request.  (within the constraints set by those cookies... usually within a certain domain...) So once your browser has saved them, you're good.